# How to change the header of the zip archive (PK to PIRAKA)?

Tags: python, archive, zip, php-ziparchive

How to change the header of the zip archive (PK to PIRAKA)? I changed the zipfile module in python. I need to create a zip archives with header PIRAKA instead of PK (archive turns out to create). **The problem is that you cannot open the file in 'r' mode.**[Pirfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-N3PX724THzf3_KpRhW--LzeOM6JNHD-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question by adding more details about your problem

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the ZIP file content in binary mode:

```
with open('file.zip', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().replace(b'PK', b'PIRAKA')

with open('result.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Input ZIP file header:

```
PK    ™QЉNLщFCё ...
```

Output ZIP file header:

```
PIRAKA    ™QЉNLщFCё ...
```

Comment: no, it's not a solution: it's just a replacement. Here is a link to my file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-N3PX724THzf3_KpRhW--LzeOM6JNHD-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I need to be able to open the file with PIRAKA header in 'r' mode. Link to my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-N3PX724THzf3_KpRhW--LzeOM6JNHD-/view

Comment: No, I just want to create my own archive type (regular zip, but with a new header) .

Comment: Much simple is to create ZIP with standard library and then replace the header

Comment: Yes, it's simple, but I'm able to create an archive with the modified library. But, can't be open in 'r' mode

Comment: You can't do it since it is binary file

Comment: PIRAKA     ”†ЉNсOKU         new.txt123456789101112PIRAKA      ”†ЉNсOKU                 ¶Ѓ    new.txtPIRAKA      7   6

Comment: fragments from pirfile.py: 
structEndArchive = "<6s4H2LH"
stringEndArchive = "PIRAKA\005\006"
structCentralDir = "<6s4B4HL2L5H2L"
stringCentralDir = "PIRAKA\001\002"
structFileHeader = "<6s2B4HL2L2H"
stringFileHeader = "PIRAKA\003\004"
structEndArchive64Locator = "<6sLQL"
stringEndArchive64Locator = "PIRAKA\x06\x07"
structEndArchive64 = "<6sQ2H2L4Q"
stringEndArchive64 = "PIRAKA\x06\x06"